# z-index set to highest but still appears beneath

Tags: html, css, image, hover, z-index

z-index is set to 350 but when you hover over the twitter image the popup still appears beneath? I would be forever grateful if you could take a look at the html and css:

Thanks a million.

Kelly.

Comment: Before going deeper, please ensure that you html and css pass validation: [html](http://validator.w3.org/), [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: I don't see there in the CSS any element with `z-index:350`. But, most of the `position:absolute` elements you have there, also have a `float` property. These two collide. In short: what Milan said

Comment: Thanks I will css validate right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
#home .carousel {
   width: 475px;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:  ...
}
```

to this

```
#home .carousel {
   width: 475px;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   overflow: visible;
   background:  ...
}
```

It seems to solve your problem.